# Variance of an unbiased estimator $L = \frac\pi4\sqrt{X_1X_2}$

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, variance, expected-value

Find variance of unbiased estimator L, where $L = \dfrac\pi4\sqrt{X_1X_2}$.

$f(x) = \dfrac1\theta e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}}$, $x>0$,

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, and exponentially distributed.

Since $L$ is unbiased so I know $E[L] = \theta$, right?

Also, $\operatorname{Var}[x] = E[x^2] - E[x]^2$. But I'm struggling with finding $E[x^2]$. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How can the "estimator" $L$ depend on the quantity $\theta$ being estimated?

Comment: @jesterll edited.

Comment: You are given $E(L)$. Now look at $E(L^2)=\text{const.}E(X_1X_2)$. Now use the independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$. The variance of $L$ is $E(L^2)-E(L)^2$.

Comment: From $\operatorname{Var}(L)=\frac{\pi^2}{16}\operatorname{Var}(\sqrt{X_1X_2})=\frac{\pi^2}{16}\left[E(X_1X_2)-(E(\sqrt{X_1X_2}))^2\right]$, the only thing that needs calculating is $E(\sqrt{X_1})$. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\bracks{L} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x_{1}/\theta} \over \theta}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x_{2}/\theta} \over \theta}
\pars{{\pi \over 4}\root{x_{1}x_{2}}}\dd x_{1}\,\dd x_{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pi \over 4}\pars{\root{\theta}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x_{1}/\theta}
\,\root{x_{1} \over \theta}\,{\dd x_{1} \over \theta}}
\\[2mm] & \phantom{===\,}
\pars{\root{\theta}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x_{2}/\theta}\,\root{x_{2} \over \theta}
\,{\dd x_{2} \over \theta}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pi \over 4}\
\underbrace{\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1/2}\expo{-x}\dd x}^{2}}
_{\ds{=\ \Gamma^{2}\pars{3/2}\ =\ {\pi/4}}}\ \theta\ =\
\bbx{{\pi^{2} \over 16}\,\theta}
\\[1cm]
\mathbb{E}\bracks{L^{2}} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x_{1}/\theta} \over \theta}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x_{2}/\theta} \over \theta}
\pars{{\pi \over 4}\root{x_{1}x_{2}}}^{2}\dd x_{1}\,\dd x_{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pi^{2} \over 16}\pars{\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-x_{1}/\theta}\,{x_{1} \over \theta}
\,{\dd x_{1} \over \theta}}
\pars{\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-x_{2}/\theta}\,{x_{1} \over \theta}
\,{\dd x_{2} \over \theta}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{\pi^{2} \over 16}\,\theta^{2}}
\\[1cm]
\mbox{Var}\pars{L} & =
\bbx{{\pi^{2} \over 16}\pars{1 - {\pi^{2} \over 16}}\theta^{2}}
\end{align}